# How can I get CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized state

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using the CBCentralManager in CoreBluetooth framework to get Bluetooth Low Energy state updates from iPhone. But I didn't find a way to get the CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized state. If I turn Bluetooth off, I'll just get the CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff state. I couldn't find a way to disable Bluetooth Low Energy on the iPhone. Is it impossible with iPhone? Is there any other device that can toggle Bluetooth Low Energy?

Comment: You should get the unauthorised state if you set the Bluetooth background capability and then deny the background permisssion when the app is first launched

Comment: So the CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized state can only happen when the app is running in the background right?

Comment: As far as I know. There is no permission required to access Bluetooth in the foreground

Comment: Thanks for the reply!